# Efficiently storing a subprocess popen object in python to use it later

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a program in python which calls a C# program using subprocess. This c# program will run for hours. And a certain event has to trigger a key press in the c# program. I can PIPE this key press with the process object.

The issue is I want to store this subprocess popen object in some kind of list or database efficiently. As I could have multiple calls to this c# program. And would like to access each specific popen object at any given time and send in a input.

I would also like to call this python script from flask so that i have a web interface.

Things that I have tried so far.

1) Use psutil to send signal such as CTRL_C_EVENT. It doesnt work as expected. But this has the advantage of storing only the pid instead of the whole object.
2) Storing the whole object in mongodatabase. This fails when i try to pickle the popen object.

Please let me know if you need additional details.

Comment: Why can't you keep them in memory, in a list or dictionary, popen objects are fairly light weight? This is definitely an object you can't pickle or store, due to the nature of how the subprocess is called and the connection to stdio is maintained. Do you have access to the C# programs source, a simple RPC system sounds like what you're looking for here.

Comment: @AronVietti Yes I have the source code for the c# program. Do you have some suggestions for simple RPC system that I should look into? The problem with storing them in memory is the process could end inadvertently and i could loose them, since these programs are supposed to run for a days at a stretch.

Comment: you should ask two separate questions: 1- "how to send keys to your C# program?" 2- "how to start and store C# program in flask such that you could send it keys later?" -- if you can't answer the first question there is no point to try to answer the second one.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian thanks for your reply. Apologies if I didn't explain it properly. I am able to send in key presses to C# program using subprocess. So first question of yours is not a concern to me, The second question is what I am looking for. Anyways I was able to solve it by creating a socket server in C# which will listen for connections. I make connection from python program and now can send in inputs anytime I want as long as the socket server is running. 

But still would like to have an answer if there is a way to do this better.

Comment: @bharani  1- if you can send keys then what is it about: *"Use psutil to send signal such as CTRL_C_EVENT. It doesnt work as expected. But this has the advantage of storing only the pid instead of the whole object."*? Why do you mention it? 2- if you want to communicate with c# processes even if your python process that started them has died then at a minimum you need sockets (so that you could reconnect).  You probably want a message broker to implement an analog of a distributed job queue such as [rq](http://python-rq.org).